# ping using python and save to a file

Tags: python, csv

Ping_Python
Below is Code to ping hosts and create a CSV file out of the results.

```
import os
for i in range (0,255):
    for j in range(1,254):
        hostname = "10.222.{0}.{1}".format(i,j)
        response = os.system ("ping -n 1 " + hostname)
        if response == 0:
            fp = open("C:\\Users\\anudeepa\\Desktop\\hostname.csv", 'w')
            fp.writelines(hostname + "host up\n")

        else:
            fp = open("C:\\Users\\anudeepa\\Desktop\\hostname.csv", 'w')
            fp.write(hostname + "host dead\n")
```

This code allows me to ping hosts,but while writing the results to a CSV, it overwrites the previously written result and only writes penultimate or unltimate result.

Answer (score 2):

Change both of

`fp = open("C:\\Users\\anudeepa\\Desktop\\hostname.csv", 'w')`

to

`fp = open("C:\\Users\\anudeepa\\Desktop\\hostname.csv", 'a')`

in order to open the file in append mode.

You can also improve your code by using `with`, so you don't open the file every iteration:

```
import os

with open("C:\\Users\\anudeepa\\Desktop\\hostname.csv", 'a') as fp:
    for i in range (0,255):
        for j in range(1,254):
            hostname = "10.222.{0}.{1}".format(i,j)
            response = os.system ("ping -n 1 " + hostname)
            if response == 0:
                fp.writelines(hostname + "host up\n")
            else:
                fp.write(hostname + "host dead\n")
```

This will also have the benefit of closing the file when the script ends.

Comment: Hi Deepspace,

Fixed the code with this correction, added the line below after "import os", opened the file globally.



**fp = open(r"C:\Users\anudeepa\Desktop\Work\Bala\xyz.csv", 'w')**
`